# Why is Athena "gray eyed"?

Tags: greek, athena, etymology

Obviously because her eyes are that color, but I suspect there are deeper, symbolic reasons for that particular color and description.

This is in regard to the epithet [γλαυκῶπις](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=glaukw%3Dpis&la=greek&can=glaukw%3Dpis0&prior=glaukw/pion#lexicon), in the lexicon defined as "bright eyed", but which is often translated as "gray eyed" by poets.

Comment: A very considerable part of the reason she is thus characterized is simply that the collocation γλαυκῶπις Άθήνη conforms to metrical requirements for the last two and a half feet of the dactylic hexameter line.

Comment: For more info on the translation, Guy Duetscher's book "Through The Language Glass" talks about the difference of perception of color culturally, giving examples of problems in translations from Ancient Greek

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word γλαυκῶπις shares its root with γλαύξ, the word for owl.

Owls are known for their large and distinctive eyes, which are adapted for low light hunting. Thus, I believe the epithet is a comment on Athena's perceptiveness, telling us that the goddess of wisdom can see even through the dark.

You may find more information on Athena's association with owls in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owl_of_Athena).

Comment: So why would gray be equivalent to see-in-the-dark/perceptive?

Comment: @bleh perhaps it is the idea that the mean of darkness (black) and light (white) is grey.  Balance was definitely an important concept to influential, early Greek philosophers such as Epicurus and Protagoras.
 [See σωφροσύνη/sophrosunē: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=swfrosu%2Fnh&la=greek&can=swfrosu%2Fnh0&prior=au)toswfrosu/nh]

Comment: @bleh I don't think it is. There are numerous valid translations of γλαυκῶπις, my opinion here is that the symbolism is hidden in the association with owls, not in the color. I think what Homer intented was to tell us Athena was "owl eyed", not gray, or blue, or green eyed. Interestingly the homeric epithet for Hera is similar - cow eyed.

Comment: Found this interesting link re: Athena as gray in Hegel on Stack Philosophy: "[When philosophy paints its gray on gray, then has a form of life grown old, and with gray on gray it cannot be rejuvenated, but only known; the Owl of Minerva first takes flight with twilight closing in."](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/43590/25828)

Comment: Found this link.  Not a reliable source, but interesting nonetheless: ['One of her epithets (titles) is "gray-eyed." Her gift to the Greeks was the useful olive tree. The underside of the olive tree's leaf is gray, and when the wind lifts the leaves, it shows Athena's many "eyes".'](https://www.tripsavvy.com/facts-about-greek-goddess-athena-1524422).

Comment: Owls were very common in Athens, and thus associated with her.

Answer (score 5):

The currently preferred view of Greek etymologists is that γλαύξ "owl" and the colour-adjective γλαυκός (in Homer the colour of the sea, later generally “grey”) are not etymologically connected. If γλαυκῶπις is connected with the former, then it means "with the eyes of an owl", not "grey-eyed". The owl is Athena’s special animal; she is generally represented with an owl on her shoulder.

Comment: You make a really good point about how the scholarship can change as the science of etymology continues to progress.  (Science notwithstanding, associations made by later poets and translators still dominate in the literary sphere.  In some sense, this was an impetus for the question.)  Very useful answer!

Answer (score 4):

It depends, as Yannis said, on the translation. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athena) says:

> In Homer's epic works, Athena's most common epithet is Glaukopis
>   (γλαυκῶπις), which usually is translated as, "bright-eyed" or "with
>   gleaming eyes". The word is a combination of glaukós (γλαυκός, meaning
>   "gleaming, silvery", and later, "bluish-green" or "gray") and ṓps (ὤψ,
>   "eye, face"). It is interesting to note that glaúx (γλαύξ, "little
>   owl") is from the same root, presumably according to some, because of
>   the bird's own distinctive eyes.

Answer (score 2):

If the word for "grey-eyed" and "owl" share a linguistic history, then the correct translation would be "bright-eyed" since literally it would read, "with the eyes of an owl" which generally fall in the spectrum of yellow or a neighboring color. This would make sense being that the owl is almost always associated with Athene

Comment: Not necessarily, the feathers of Athenian owls are grey(ish). Although the more common translations for γλαυκῶπις assume it's a reference to the distinctiveness of owl eyes, there's no reason why the epithet can't be a poetic reference to the bird's colour. "grey-eyed" isn't an incorrect translation.

Comment: @yannis This prompts me to go deeper into the descriptions of Athena's eyes being highly metaphoric--never is she thought of as having yellow or orange eyes.  So she may be owl-eyed and bright-eyed, but the owlishness and brightness would relate to her keen perception, as you note in your answer, as opposed to the literal color.  Solsdottir also notes the association of γλαυκός first with silvery, then bluish-green or gray.  *(Through Pallas-daughter-of-Triton, Athena is associated with the sea, often bluish-green or gray.)*

Comment: @C-2 PS, welcome to Mythology!

Comment: I'm not even sure that owls are supposed to have bright eyes.  Bubo bubo has noticable yellow or orange eyes, but also distinctive large ears and a big triangular forehead close to its eyes. The images of owls that I've seen associated with Athena don't like like that at all.  They look more like stylized images of Strix aluco, with no visible ears, and a flat face with a smaller forehead far from its eyes.  And as far as I can tell Stirx aluco has dark eyes.

Comment: I was probably wrong about that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_owl#In_human_culture suggests that Athena may be associated to the species Athene noctua, which does have bright yellow eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Lately I have been reading terence McKenna. He thinks there is a connection between glaucous (meaning blue gray) and rituals. He suggests that there is a connection between the blue gray color of the musk (light film) on grapes. It's a blue gray color. He also suggests the glaucous color has connections with the color of a bruised mushroom. And, the more I learn about greek myth I read about eye opening  hallucinogenics that could be the food of the gods. That people who visited Eleusis and participated the ritual there. were taking a combination of wine, mushrooms and other herbs. musky blue-gray, silvery gleam, bright eyed. I am sure there are many more interpolation attempts. I read about Glaucous, Deucalion, and now Athena. The more I read the more i find that greek rituals were about ever lasting life. birth, death, and rebirth. Seeing the real world, the real truth. The person becomes immoral.

Answer (score 1):

Mythic authors didn't just use etymology, but used paronomasia, parallel naming employing names that are parallel by meaning, or by visual, or, phonetic structure.
Athena is Grey-eyed because olives are grey. She symbolizes the olive harvest. Athena gave the olive tree to Athens. It is the year's last harvest, associating mature age with wisdom as ancients often did.